# moving files matching a pattern that catches the directory

Tags: bash, regex, wildcards, mv

Consider:

```
$ ls
foo  xyfooz.tex
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*foo*' -exec mv {} foo \;
$ ls ./foo*
xyfooz.tex
```

I'm trying to achieve the same sequence of instructions only with mv, not find:

```
$ ls
foo  xyfooz.tex
$ mv *foo* foo
mv: cannot stat '*foo*': No such file or directory
$ ls ./foo*
xyfooz.tex
```

Additionally (edit),

```
$ ls -F
foo/  xyfooz.tex*
$ mv -v *foo* foo

mv: cannot move 'foo' to a subdirectory of itself, 'foo/foo'
'xyfooz.tex' -> 'foo/xyfooz.tex'
```

How to make sure the 'stat' warning does not appear. In other words, I guess, I would I refine the pattern to limit the source to files not directories?

GNU bash, 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="18.3 (Sylvia)"
```

Comment: It's not clear what is going on, but shell expansion can't be limited to files: you need to use `find` or `for f in *foo*; do [ -f "$f" ] && mv "$f" foo; done`. Please update your question with the results on repeating both tests using `ls -F` each time and `mv -v` in both the `find ... -exec` and the stand-alone command. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.04 with `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. If `foo` is a directory and `xyfooz.tex` a file, my stand-alone `mv` gives `mv: cannot move 'foo' to a subdirectory of itself, 'foo/foo'`, which is as expected. What OS are you using?

Comment: I have made edits according to your suggestion, but they don't tell us anything new. I'm using the same bash version, that was already in the question. I would have hoped there existed a regex way to restrict the source to type file.

Answer (score 2):

#### With `mv`

`cannot move 'foo' to a subdirectory of itself` is harmless in this case, you can ignore it. I mean `mv` will move the rest despite the warning. However the exit status will not be `0`, this may be a great obstacle in scripts where you want to abort or to take a correcting action if `mv` doesn't succeed.

This has been already [said in a comment](https://superuser.com/q/1314356/432690#comment1956059_1314356): you can silence `mv` by redirecting stderr with `2>/dev/null`; other warnings or errors will be redirected as well though.

I think you cannot easily "refine the pattern to limit the source to files not directories". Still you can take an approach that doesn't match the literal `foo`. The following approach has nothing to do with files or directories; just with names, because globs deal with names; so it may not be enough in some cases.

The `*foo*` glob matches four disjunctive kinds of objects:

1. `foo` itself
2. foo with prefix only, like `bar-foo` – you can match them by `*?foo`
3. foo with prefix and postfix, like `bar-foo-baz` – `*?foo?*`
4. foo with postfix only, like `foo-baz` – `foo?*`

To exclude `foo` you need the latter three (2-4) only, so the first approach may be:

```
mv *?foo *?foo?* foo?* foo/
```

Unless you have the `nullglob` shell option set, any pattern needs to match something, otherwise it will be passed to `mv` literally. You don't want this. The solution is to run the following command beforehand:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

This shell option will make any unmatched glob expand to nothing. I advise you to research `dotglob` option as well.

Note that `*?foo*` matches (2-3). Similarly `*foo?*` matches (3-4). Additionally consider `--` to tell `mv` that all following arguments aren't options. This way a file like `--foo` won't be interpreted as an (unknown) option. This leads to two better commands:

```
mv -- *?foo* foo?* foo/
```

or

```
mv -- *?foo *foo?* foo/
```

It doesn't matter which one you choose. Just don't use `mv *?foo* *foo?* foo/`; it will pass (e.g.) `bar-foo-baz` to `mv` twice (i.e. as two separate arguments), thus generating an error when the tool tries to move this object for the second time.

When no match is found at all, my `mv` commands will degenerate themselves to `mv foo/` and throw an error. Your original `mv` command (with `nullglob` unset) would get the literal `*foo*` and throw another error.

---

Example console session:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ mkdir foo
$ touch bar-foo bar-foo-baz foo-baz xyfooz.tex ./--foo
$ mv -v -- *?foo* foo?* foo/
'bar-foo' -> 'foo/bar-foo'
'bar-foo-baz' -> 'foo/bar-foo-baz'
'--foo' -> 'foo/--foo'
'xyfooz.tex' -> 'foo/xyfooz.tex'
'foo-baz' -> 'foo/foo-baz'
$
```

---

#### Simple hack

Let's say `dummy` doesn't exist.

```
mv foo dummy
mv *foo* dummy/
mv dummy foo
```

Renaming a directory should be very fast in inode-based filesystems. Programs having files from within `foo/` already opened shouldn't interfere nor break because it's the inode that matters. However if any program needs to open a file (by its path including `foo/`) between the first and the third `mv`, it will fail. Other side effects may occur (imagine a third party program recreating `foo/` in the meantime), that's why I call this approach a hack. Think twice before you use it.

---

#### With `find` anyway

Telling apart files from directories is a job for `find`. What you did with `find` is basically the right way. What you want to do (and what I did above) with `mv` and shell globbing seems… well, "less right" at most. This is your command:

> ```
> find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*foo*' -exec mv {} foo \;
> ```

This `find` will run a separate `mv` for every matched file, the whole command will perform poorly. For this reason one may want to switch to a single `mv`. If this is your line of thought (and your `mv` and `find` are rich enough) then you should consider this "very right" way:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*foo*' -exec mv -t foo/ -- {} +
```

The advantages over your `find` command and/or over plain `mv` with glob(s):

- a single `mv` may get multiple files to work with;
- still, if there are too many files for one command line to handle, `find` will run additional `mv` process(es);
- in a case when no file matches the pattern, `mv` won't be run at all;
- thanks to `--` a file like `--foo` will not be interpreted as an (unknown) option to `mv`;

Comment: Comprehensive, just wanted to say thanks, will look into it.